# ElasticSearch remove all documents with over 1000 fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting this error:

[image]

While updating a dev ElasticSearch DB from a LIVE one. I believe it is being caused because the live DB is sending ***documents*** with over ***1000 fields*** in them and the dev DB ***index.mapping.total_fields.limit*** is set to ***1000***

I know I can up the fields limit, but for now I would like to just ***remove*** all ***documents*** with ***1000 or more fields***.

I'm guessing make a Postman call to the _delete_by_query API with something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "fields": {
        "gt": 1000
      }
     }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know of a simple query that can accomplish this?

Comment: So you want to call `_delete_by_query` against the live cluster just because the Dev one doesn't support more than 1000 fields ?

Comment: Moreover, as you've just accepted [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49933432/4604579) about the same subject, you can definitely use it in this context, too. Unless of course your documents contain nested fields, in which case the script is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Val I believe your answer is correct... Add it to this one and I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query like this against the LIVE cluster:

```
POST logger/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": "params._source.size() > 1000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Provided you don't have nested fields/objects, this will delete all documents having more than 1000 fields.