# ElasticSearch how to get docs with 10 or more fields in them?

Tags: elasticsearch, cypher

I want to get all docs that have 10 or more fields in them. I'm guessing something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "fields": {
        "gt": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to run a script query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "source": "params._source.size() >= 10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, be advised that depending on the number of documents you have and the hardware that supports your cluster, this can negatively impact the performance of your cluster.

A better idea would be to add another integer field that contains the number of fields that the document contains, so you can simply run a `range` query on it, like in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As Per Documentation of _source field, you can do this like that or can't get results based on fields count.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html